# Are there any PDF libraries for J2ME?

Tags: pdf, java-me

We need to create a basic PDF reader running on J2ME. While there are several PDF libraries for Java, I'm not sure whether they support J2ME.

Does anyone know a working J2ME PDF library? If not, why it's so hard to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use JPedal for Java ME. You can find details [here](http://www.jpedal.org/java_me_pdf_viewer.php).